# add dynamically created class to an element

Tags: css, angular

currently I'm working on an enhanced grid in Angular. For this I created a custom directive. Now, I want to achieve the following.

To create a frozen column, we need the following class on the grid:

```
.enhanced.k-grid th:nth-child(1),
.enhanced.k-grid td:nth-child(1) {
  position: sticky !important;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.enhanced.k-grid th:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

This makes the first column frozen. If we want to make also the 2. column frozen, we add new selectors to the style sheet and change 1 to 2 and change the `left` property with the cumulated width of the columns accordingly.

Currently if I want to make let's say the first 5 column frozen, I have to repeat the above classes with modified parameters. They would be in this way predefined in the stylesheet.

In my directive I set up an input property, where the user can define the columns to be frozen (so I can get their indexes) and I also have access to the width of the columns.

So, everything is given. The question is, how can I

- create the css selector?
- change the parameters (in the selector and also in the style)?
- add this css class to the host (grid)?

`NgClass`, `@HostBinding`, `Renderer2` deal with adding or removing **existing** classes. But in my case I don't want to predefine let's say 10 classes with fixed parameters. I want to add these selectors (classes) dynamically to the host. How to do that?

Comment: You can binding one class and the style.left: `[class.stucky]="colIndex<numFrozen" [style.left.px]="offdet[colIndex]"`

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do that is to have a string in your component which you can dynamically change based on the application state. You can also dynamically control specific style attributes.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="static-class {{customClasses}}" [style.width]="width+'px'">
      My Content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './mycomp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycomp.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   customClasses = '';
   width = 0;

   ngOnInit() {
     // Do some work
     customClasses = 'my-class second-class'
     width = 100;
   }
}
```